# Python pandas data restructure

Tags: python, pandas

I need to extract data from stock prices and I have build a code which provides me the values in below format:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAECA.png)

But I need this data to be in the format below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M58RA.png)

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49479902/reshaping-long-data-to-wide-in-python-pandas and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df_in = pd.DataFrame({'Volume': [12575, 5630, 240],
                  'High': [148] * 3,
                  'Time': ['4:15', ' 5:30', '6:30']})

df_in.index = df_in.index + 1

df_out = df_in.stack().to_frame().T

df_out.columns = [f'{j}{i}' for i, j in df_out.columns]

df_out
```

Output:

```
  Volume1 High1 Time1 Volume2 High2  Time2 Volume3 High3 Time3
0   12575   148  4:15    5630   148   5:30     240   148  6:30
```

Comment: I think you meant "4:15" not "4:!5" feel free to change it back if I was incorrect =)

Answer (score 1):

Input data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Volume": [12575, 5630, 2430], "High": [148, 148, 148], "Time": ["4:15", "5:30", "6:30"]}, index=[1, 2, 3])
```

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns, df.index.astype(str)]).map(''.join)

df = df.unstack().to_frame().set_index(idx).transpose()
```

Output result

```
>>> df
  Volume1 Volume2 Volume3 High1 High2 High3 Time1 Time2 Time3
0   12575    5630    2430   148   148   148  4:15  5:30  6:30
```

*Updated following @[HenryEcker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15497888/henry-ecker)'s comment*

Comment: [`Index.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html#pandas-index-map) is another option to flatten the index directly from the MultiIndex instead of `to_flat_index().str.join()`. `pd.MultiIndex.from_product(...).map(''.join)`